# How do I enable Flash for a specific app in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flash

In Chrome, I would like to enable Flash for a specific app (in my case, it's called ARC Welder). I went to `chrome://settings/content/flash` where I see the following screen:

[image: Flash settings screen]

There is a list called *Block* and another list called *Allow*. As you see on the image, ARC Welder is in the *Block* list and no matter what I tried, I cannot remove it from the list and put it in *Enable* instead. How am I supposed to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, Chrome now blocks flash content starting in December of last year (2016). To enable flash you must [create an exception](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/chrome-55-now-blocks-flash-uses-html5-by-default/) for Chrome's flash-blocking policy.

In Chrome go to `Settings` > `Content Settings` > `Flash` > `Manage Exceptions` and add the website you are having problems with to the expections. Also, pester the webmasters of that site to update to HTML5. Seriously... it's time.

Comment: Thanks -- this is the same advice I've seen on the internet, but it may be outdated; there is no "Manage Exceptions" under "Flash" (see http://i.imgur.com/rgVwUIu.png). If I select the right arrow next to "Flash", I am directed to the page I mentioned in my post (chrome://settings/content/flash) which is where I'm having my problem; I cannot remove the app from the "Block" list. Do you know of the solution?

Comment: For anyone else who is reading this: the above advice is definitely outdated; there is no "Manage Exceptions" under "Flash" anymore.

Comment: Hmm, so it is. But adding the site to the allow list there should work. If it's not then there must be a deeper problem. Assuming "Allow sites to run Flash" is also enabled. In fact, really, it should have prompted you to allow flash when you visited the page and it loaded a flash applet. That it won't let you move it to the allow list is rather strange.

Comment: It isn't a website, it's a Google Chrome app from the Chrome Web Store. How do you add an app to the Enable list?

Comment: Ah, see that part wasn't completely clear. Apologies. I thought you meant an app embedded in a website. I'm not sure that you can. I'm afraid that being the case I'm not sure what you can do except pester the creator of the app to update it properly.

Comment: Well, Google is the creator of Arc Welder :) Not sure if I can pester them. Thank you for the help, though.